# Why does $\lVert x\rVert$ equal $\sup_{\lVert x'\rVert \leq 1} \lVert xx'\rVert$ in a C*-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

This is on page 9 of Dixmier's **C*-algebra**

> Let $A$ be a C*-algebra. For each $x \in A$, we have $$\lVert x\rVert = \sup_{\lVert x'\rVert \leq 1}\lVert xx'\rVert.$$

To prove this, the author says

> It is clear that $\lVert x'\rVert \leq 1$ implies $\lVert xx'\rVert \leq \lVert x\rVert$. To show that $\lVert x\rVert \leq \sup_{\lVert x'\rVert \leq 1} \lVert xx'\rVert$, we can assume that $\lVert x \rVert =1$; then $\lVert x^\ast\rVert =1$ and $\sup_{\lVert x'\rVert \leq 1} \lVert xx'\rVert \geq \lVert xx^\ast \rVert = \lVert x\rVert^2 =1$.

I am confusioned by the last sentenced, which states $\sup_{\lVert x'\rVert \leq 1} \lVert xx'\rVert \geq \lVert xx^\ast\rVert$. But why does it hold?

Would anyone please give some explanation?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Observe that $x^\ast \in \{x' : \lVert x'\rVert \leq 1\}$ and use the definition of the supremum.

Comment: @commenter: Sincere thanks for taking time to edit my question and answer it. I am sorry I just begin to study C*-algebra and I am not quite familiar with the notations. Thanks for tha answer again. I realize this is not a good question and I don't know why I was stuck here...

Comment: Dear ShinyaSakai. You are welcome. I think Dixmier is a very good book, but it might be a bit terse if you're just starting out with C\*-algebras (many people consider it hard to read). Maybe you could read some less specialized book first? Many books on functional analysis contain introductions to C\*-algebras, for example Conway or Pedersen. Concerning the notation with norms: It looks a bit better to use `\|..\|` or `\lVert..\rVert` in place of `||..||`. On mathoverflow using `*` instead of `\ast` sometimes gives problems with the formatting, so I would suggest to use the latter.

Comment: Dear @commenter: Thanks again. I'll remember what you said on notations. As this book is suggested by my teacher, I think I will continue with it while reading the books you mentioned which are easier to follow.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\sup ||xx'||\geq ||x\frac{x^\ast}{||x||}||=\frac{||xx^\ast||}{||x||}=||x||$